# Picasso for Android does not seem to fetch images when using mobile data

Tags: java, android, picasso

I created an android application that calls an API that pulls back JSON. This works when on WiFi and when using mobile data.

I implemented Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) into my application to pull back an image in a separate request.
When I am on WiFi it fetches the image from a URL. If I am using mobile data (4G), it looks like it tries to make the request but fails and uses the error image.

```
Picasso.with(_context).load(url).error(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.image);
```

Is this to do with the Picasso's library or the way I implemented it. Do I need to override anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say. There are a couple of things you can do to gather more information. In your `Application.onCreate`: `Picasso.setSingletonInstance(new Picasso.Builder(this).loggingEnabled(true).listener(new Listener() {}).build());` I left out the implementation of `Listener` for space reasons but you can add additional logging there. This should give you some hints as to what is going wrong.